# exclude certain clj namespaces from compilation in leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I have a project that works fine using `lein run`. Now I want to compile it into a standalone jar using `lein uberjar`. However, there are a couple of source files in my `src/projectname/` directory called e.g. `playground.clj` and `stats.clj` that I use for experimenting with emacs & the repl, but that I don't want to compile for the final project.

With something like `make`, I would specify all files that should be compiled. With clojure/leiningen, it seems, all files are compiled by default - **how can I exclude files**? I haven't found anything in the leiningen docs.

I am currently using `:aot :all`. Is this the place to change something? Again, I couldn't find detailed documentation on this.

**UPDATE:**

The suggestions so far haven't worked. What has worked, however, is to *include* all desired namespaces instead of excluding the ones that should not be compiled. E.g.:

```clj
(defproject myproject "version"
  ;; ...
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot [myproject.data
                             myproject.db
                             myproject.util]}})
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [leiningen's sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/63305fc/sample.project.clj#L407-L413), which describes how to use `:jar-exclusions` or `:uberjar-exclusions` to exclude arbitrary paths when creating jars (resp. uberjars).

```
  ;; Files with names matching any of these patterns will be excluded from jars.
  :jar-exclusions [#"(?:^|/).svn/"]
  ;; Files with names matching any of these patterns will included in the jar
  ;; even if they'd be skipped otherwise.
  :jar-inclusions [#"^\.ebextensions"]
  ;; Same as :jar-exclusions, but for uberjars.
  :uberjar-exclusions [#"META-INF/DUMMY.SF"]
```

Comment: tried `:uberjar-exclusions [#".*stats.clj" #".*playground.clj"]`, didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think I found the answer for those coming after me.

I found the answer in the link to the sample leiningen project from @amalloy's answer, except instead of `:jar-exclusions` I use `source-paths`, [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/63305fc/sample.project.clj#L300).

The idea is to create *two separate source directories*, one for stuff you don't care to spread around and one for stuff you do:

```
dev-src/<your-project>/playground.clj
dev-src/<your-project>/stats.clj
src/<your-project>/<everything-else>
```

Then, in your project.clj, include `src` in `source-paths` normally, and include `emacs-src` in a special profile where your want it visible, say the usual `:dev` profile:

```clj
{
   ;; ...
   :source-paths ["src"]
   :profiles {
      :dev {
         :source-paths ["src" "dev-src"]
      }
   }
}
```

That way when you're messing around on your machine those files will be in the jar, and when you deploy to clojars or compile with uberjar they will not be included in the jar, nor compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(ns ^:skip-aot my-ns)`

You can also do

```
(ns ^{:skip-aot true} my-ns
    (require [...]))
```

[Source](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/9f2f9eb6956d6571df9922d786728adec150a2b1/sample.project.clj#L208)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Does this have anything to do with it? -> From the same source file: "^:skip-aot will not disable AOT compilation of :main when :aot is :all or contains the main class." I.e. I'd then need to replace :all by a vector of all files to include?

Comment: That's correct. You can move code from the main ns to another and add `^:skip-aot` to the namespace

Comment: Well, my main ns is called `myproject.core`. I added `^:skip-aot` to the `ns` directive in `myproject.stats` but when I run `lein uberjar` it still wants to compile `stats`. I could only resolve the issue by renaming `stats.clj` to `stats.bak`.

Comment: I assume that your main ns, `myproject.core`, depends on code in `myproject.stats`.  Is there any reason why you can't define which namespaces need `:aot` instead of using `:all`?

Comment: I checked, of course. There is no such dependency. `stats` is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: What version of lein are you using?

Comment: Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_65 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: Can you try upgrading to Lein 2.5 and then check if the issue still occurs?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked-to project.clj, `^:skip-aot` is only relevant for the namespace listed as `:main` in project.clj: it doesn't do anything elsewhere, because other namespaces are either (a) not AOT compiled to begin with, or (b) AOT compiled iff an AOT-compiled `:main` namespace depends on them.

Comment: `:aot :all` seems to cancel the `^:skip-aot` flag. Leiningen 2.5 doesn't change this.